# Pattern for a Singleton containing lists

Tags: java

I have various small lookup tables in my application where I don't want to query the database every time they are requested. So I want to only read these once when the singleton object is first requested.   The only issue I can see is if a user wants to edit records in these tables, I need to reset and reload the objects in the list again.

Is there a thread safe pattern for having a Singleton used for storing and retrieving lists of objects?

Comment: do you mean that you want to have an object in your Java app that can work as a cache for the database?

Comment: Yes. It would read the list of objects once in it's constructor and then then application would use the cached versions.  I'm trying to think how it would work with threads since the user may modify these lists.

Comment: users modify lookup? Usually these kind of lists are read only.

Comment: why not use an ORM, use the Java Persistence API, the handles do what you need.

Comment: @Nishant - Sure. Let's say you have a list of Categories for sales orders. An admin user could edit this list at any time.

Comment: @Jhonathan Yes. We use an ORM.  We have a list of objects read from a database.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) which is thread safe.

Comment: Interesting. How is this different from a Concurrent collection?

Comment: Not sure about the differences, I haven't evaluated the two options against each other. As I said, one **could** use that list :-)